# Nginx service is not working: "SSL: error:0906D0 - Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE"

Tags: nginx, ca

We get this error:

> nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("D:/cert/ca.cer") failed (SSL: error:0906D0
>   6C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)

When we are using a normal SSL certificate, it is working as expected.
If we replace the SSL certificate with a CA certified trusted certificate, we get the above error.

How can we solve this problem?